# Does there exist a magical backend service where front end coders can store data?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ruby-on-rails, node.js

Being a front end javascript developer, I find it a pain to develop, host, and maintain a database and backend layer to fetch and push data to the client.

What I would love is a way for me to login to some service, define schemas in xml and the database would be automatically setup.  Simple things like login widgets would be automated.  All I want to do is write a front end in JS and consume/write to APIs.

Does any such magical service exist?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, Parse.

https://parse.com/

its geared for mobile developers but you can use the rest api from anything.

https://parse.com/docs/rest

Comment: this is great, but the initial setup is very catered towards ios or android.  Is there anything out there like this but more for general web applications?

Comment: Check Ignacio's comment, they have wrappers for almost every language, or use the REST api.

Comment: http://couchdb.apache.org/ exposes a rest api for a NOSQL document database, this sort of does what your asking except theres a lot more setup.

Comment: This i guess answers my questions, but no IE6, IE7 support. Guess that's not a bad thing :)
http://blog.parse.com/2012/01/19/javascript-and-user-authentication-for-the-REST-API/

Comment: O, browser JS, according to your tags i thought you meant Node.JS

Comment: Right, was hoping to only use a server to do url routing and asset delivery.  Did not want to write any code on the backend to talk to a database.

Comment: Yeah, well apparently you can do this with XHR, but there are some security problems until they implement read-only keys etc. As far as I know what you are asking for doesn't really exist since your api key would be exposed in the client source. But Parse is probably the closest.

Comment: So if i was to build a light proxy using node.js on the backend to intercept requests on the front end, it would be secure because the key would be stored server side?

Comment: Yes and you could probably get it to work with IE6/7, because you would eliminate the CORS problems.